# Accessing a .NET Core Web API via AJAX when the user is logged into a Web Application

Tags: ajax, azure, asp.net-core, openid, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a project using .NET Core that has a Web Application and a Web API (I'm doing it this way so the structure can be n-tiered). Both are authenticated using OpenID / Azure Active Directory. The user can log into the web application without any problems.

I need to access my API from both the web application side (in the code-behind -- this is done), and from the user's browser via AJAX. That is where I'm stuck, and not sure how to proceed. The cookies are all HTTPOnly, so i can't access them from the Javascript side. And, the web API is at a different base URL than the web application.

I do have my applications in Azure setup so that logging into the web app also grants permissions to log into the web api (this was at least necessary for the web app to web api communication).

So, how do I go about accessing my API from the client side?

I apologize there's no code for this. I haven't even found a way to start this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can place the two applications on different subdomains but the same root domains (Or you can reverse proxy something like maindomain.com/api/ to api.anotherdomain.com), then you will be able to share cookies. Outside of that, cookies are not able to be shared across different domains.

What you are likely going to have to do is use another claims based token system. Likely JWT (https://jwt.io/). Any search for JWT and .net core should lead you down the right path.

Comment: This is presently running on localhost. Visual Studio puts it on different ports, so different domains is the only way to go, so far. Also, when using Azure AD, it defaults to OpenID, so I'd prefer to stick with that.

Comment: Your authentication method doesn't change the fact that JWT is still your best option. JWT is a way to share claims across domains. If your website authenticates a user (However it happens, AD, Social Login etc), a token is simply returned to the user saying they are who they are. For the API, it receives the token and takes it as gospel that they are who the token says they are, they don't have to reauthenticate.

Comment: The API actually is using JWT, but I don't see how that helps me get the token in the first place.

Comment: Because your website can issue a JWT after a user logs in?

Comment: There are 5 things that are generated by the default login. `.AspNetCore.Cookies`, `.AspNetCore.CookiesC1`, `.AspNetCore.CookiesC2`, `.AspNetCore.Session`, and `Webstorm-3f4891f4`. However, all of these are HttpOnly. And, if I can't access the tokens, I don't know how to send the needed token to the API. I could go through the web app, but then that ruins the n-tieredness of the app.  Also, FWIW, none of the 5 tokens I have right now get me into the API (I tried using them with Postman).

Comment: So, maybe I need help figuring out how to issue a JWT Token security through AJAX? Would something like this work? (I just found it) https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js